# what is the difference between event.x,event.y and event.x_root,event.y_root in tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, menu

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
win=tk.Tk()
def get_event(event):
     print(f"{event.x} {event.y}")
win.bind("<Button-3>",get_event)
win.mainloop()
```

im making right click menu in tkinter but when i write event.x and event.y:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
win=tk.Tk()
menu=tk.Menu(win,tearoff=False)
menu.add_command(label="Nothing...")
def popup(event):
     menu.tk_popup(event.x,event.y)
win.bind("<Button-3>",popup)
win.mainloop()
```

the menu overflows the window
but when i write event.x_root and event.y_root in menu.tk_popup it doesn't

Comment: `event.x_root` is the absolute position of the mouse on the screen. `event.x` is the position of the mouse relative to the widget. So when you click on the far left of the widget, `event.x` will be 0. When you click on the far left of the screen (given that it triggers an event), `event.x_root` will be 0.

Comment: The difference is described in **The Event Object** section of [Events and Bindings](https://web.archive.org/web/20201111211515id_/https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm).

Comment: thank you so much <3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use `x` and `y` attributes from `event`, it refers to the x/y coordinate of the mouse at the time of the event, relative to the upper left corner of the **widget**.

But when you use `x_root` and `y_root` from `event`, it refers to the x/y coordinate of the mouse at the time of the event, relative to the upper left corner of the **screen**.