# Why is the button moving incorrectly

Tags: python, tkinter

Run this code before answering -

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('500x500')

def drag(e):
    posx,posy = e.x_root,e.y
    B1.place(x=posx,y=posy)

def size(event):
    W,H,X,Y = event.width,event.height,event.x,event.y
    root.title(f'W: {W}, H: {H}, X: {X}, Y: {Y}')

root.bind('<Configure>',size)

B1 = Button(root,text='Hi')
B1.place(x=0,y=0)

B1.bind("<B1-Motion>",drag)
```

Result:

[image]

When I try to move the button, it goes smoothly. But if I move the whole Tkinter window and then move the button, it goes somewhere else.

So, how do I fix it so that it is smooth?

EDIT: When I use e.x ..., 2 buttons are shown

Comment: Does it go rough now?

Comment: Yeah! I have checked and yes!

Comment: When my mouse cursor is in the left-top corner of my screen, the button is in the left-top corner of the tkinter window no matter where I moved the window before. So it seems like it does use your screen variables and applies them to your tkinter window or something like this.

Comment: Maybe you can make it somehow "relativ". Get the cursor poition at the click and then move the button relative distance in x and y direction of that. Does that sound logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is because functions use different coordinates -  `event.x_root` gives position on screen, not in window, and `place()` needs position in window, not on screen. There is also `event.x` which gives position inside `button` so it may not be useful.

You can use `root.winfo_rootx()` (which gives window position) to correct it.
You could also get mouse position on `Button` when you click it to correct its position when you move `Button`.

```
import tkinter as tk  # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred

# --- functions ---

def start(e):
    global offsetx
    global offsety
    
    offsetx = e.x
    offsety = e.y
    
    print(offsetx, offsety)
    
def drag(e):
    posx = e.x_root - root.winfo_rootx() - offsetx
    posy = e.y_root - root.winfo_rooty() - offsety
    button1.place(x=posx, y=posy)

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('500x500')

button1 = tk.Button(root, text='Hi')   # PEP8: `lower_case_names` for variables
button1.place(x=0, y=0)

button1.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", start)
button1.bind("<Button1-Motion>", drag)

root.mainloop()
```

---

[PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

---

**EDIT:**

Other method using `e.widget` to get widget position and relative `e.x,e.y`

```
def drag(e):
    widget = e.widget
    
    posx = widget.winfo_x() + e.x - offsetx
    posy = widget.winfo_y() + e.y - offsety

    button1.place(x=posx, y=posy)
```

Comment: I added also other version

Answer (score 0):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66890525/what-is-the-difference-between-event-x-event-y-and-event-x-root-event-y-root-in) should help you fix it.
`event.x_root` is taking the **screen** coordinates and not the **widget** coordinates. Use `event.x` instead.